# WP8 C# Button Change Click

Tags: c#, button, onclick, windows-phone-8

I am programming in C# for Windows Phone 8 and have a Windows.System.Controls.Button object which does not have a "Click" event defined in the XML upon page load.  However, after certain pieces of data are obtained, I want to set the button's click event to a specific function I have written.

How can this be done?  The "OnClick" event is protected, and I can't find which setting to change in the MSDN site.

Answer (score 2):

from the code you should be able to do something like `MyButton.Click += clickhandler`, from the XAML you also can do that.

Answer (score 1):

You can potentially change the click event of the button by doing the following:

`btButton.Click += NewHandler()`

Another way, which isn't as clean would be to have a flag that checks if you have reached a specific stage, declared globally.

`bool myBool = false;`

Then you can change the bool flag to `true` and check whether it's true in the click event:

```
if(myBool)
{
   //toDo Logic
}
```

This way you won't need to create another event handler.